# Pass the function as an argument to main function python and docker file

Tags: python, function, refactoring

Let us consider I have three files in 3 different folders.

```
folder-1:
|-file-1.py

folder-2:
|-file-2.py

folder-3:
|-file-main.py
```

file-1 contains a function:

```
def foo(*, nr1, nr2):
    return nr1 + nr2
```

file 2 contains a function:

```
def goo(*, nr1, nr2):
    return nr1 - nr2
```

file-3 is the main file that requires a function to be provided as an argument.

```
def main(func):
    inputs=dict(nr1=2, nr2=5) # reading inputs from cloud
    return func(**inputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

dockerfile contains an entrypoint as below:

```
enntrypoint["python", "-m", "folder-3.file-main", "folder-2.file-1.foo"]
```

The question is: How to pass the function as an argument through the entry point of the docker file and to be called inside the main function?

errors thrown:

```
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I tried using `eval` across the `sys.srgv[1]` and then the error is thrown for `folder_1` is not defined.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(eval(sys.argv[1])) # to remove the string formatted return of sys.argv
```

What am I missing here? I would like to pass the required function as an argument.